# Doubt in definition of derivative $\lim_{s\to 0} \frac{f(2+s)-f(2)}{2s} = 1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definition

I'm trying to solve a test and I have a doubt. Knowing the following limit

$$\lim_{s\to 0} \frac{f(2+s)-f(2)}{2s} = 1$$

can someone help me to choose the right option?

> a) $f'(2) = 1 $
>
> b) $f'(2) = 2 $
>
> c) $f'(0) = 1 $

Comment: hopefully $f$ is differentiable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that
$$\lim_{s\to0}\frac{f(2+s)-f(2)}s=2.$$
Hence, $f'(2)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{f(2+s)-f(2)}{s}=f'(2).$$

Comment: Are you sure of what you wrote?

Comment: @egreg: what do you mean ?

Comment: The edit by idm has fixed it. What you wrote was quite wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid asking test question on stack exchange. It only hinders your learning, but you get to choose how much you want to learn. What is shown in the question is the definition of the derivative multiplied by 1/2. i.e

$1/2 *f'(2)= 1$

Therefore, the answer is b.

Comment: thanks for answering I have understood it.